# Whether kafka broker have impact with 2 MB message size

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a use case where we want to produce data to kafka with max size of 2 MB rarely (That is, based on user operations message size will vary).

Whether producing 2 Mb size will have any impact or we need to split the message to small chunk such as 100 KB and produce.

If we produce into small chunk, it will increase response time for the user. Also, we have checked by producing 2 MB message to kafka and we doesn't see much latency there.

Anyway if we split the data and produce, it doesn't have any impact in disk size. But whether broker performance will degrade due to this?

Our broker configuration is:

RAM   125.6 GB
Disk Size 2.9 TB
Processors  40

Comment: with that broker I wouldn't worry about 2MB msg sizes..

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with having messages of size up to 2MB. You just need to configure the corresponding parameters;

- Set `message.max.bytes` and `replica.fetch.max.bytes` on broker side
  (Note that  `message.max.bytes` < `replica.fetch.max.bytes`).
- And `max.partition.fetch.bytes` on consumer side

to at least 2MB

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest considering more efficient, even binary data formats (ref Avro, Protobuf, MsgPack, etc) for producing data, then additionally adding compression (Zstd, GZIP, Snappy, etc) within the producer code before attempting to tweak any broker related properties